# Is it possible to trigger the "Quick-edit" function using an <a> tag from within a page outside of EPiServer edit mode?

Tags: episerver

1. Navigate to a page
2. Click the Quick-edit button (a regular a-tag)
   [image]
3. The users goes into Quick-edit mode
   [image]

Is this possible and how to achieve?

Note: The question is targeted at EPiServer 6 R2 in this particular case.

Comment: So what you need is a link that will send you to the content tab in the Edit mode of a certain page?

Comment: Yes, or to the Quick-edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johan is absolutely right. His answer works beautifully.

I wanted to share my final result:

1. Create a personal blog publically. By publically I mean you're really just using EPiServers edit-mode stuff.

   ```
   uxCreatePersonalBlog.NavigateUrl = String.Format("{0}EditPanel.aspx?parent={1}&type=82&epslanguage={2}&mode=simpleeditmode",
       UriSupport.AbsoluteUrlFromUIBySettings("edit/"),
       CurrentPage.PageLink,
       CurrentPage.LanguageBranch);

   uxCreatePersonalBlog.Visible = CurrentPage.QueryDistinctAccess(AccessLevel.Create);
   ```
2. Create a blog item publically.

   ```
   uxCreateBlogItem.NavigateUrl = String.Format("{0}EditPanel.aspx?parent={1}&type=80&epslanguage={2}&mode=simpleeditmode",
       UriSupport.AbsoluteUrlFromUIBySettings("edit/"),
       CurrentPage.PageLink,
       CurrentPage.LanguageBranch);

   uxCreateBlogItem.Visible = CurrentPage.QueryDistinctAccess(AccessLevel.Create);
   ```
3. Edit a blog item publically.

   ```
   uxEditBlogItem.NavigateUrl = String.Format("{0}Default.aspx?id={1}&epslanguage={2}&mode=simpleeditmode",
       UriSupport.AbsoluteUrlFromUIBySettings("edit/"),
       CurrentPage.PageLink,
       CurrentPage.LanguageBranch);

   uxEditBlogItem.Visible = CurrentPage.QueryDistinctAccess(AccessLevel.Edit);
   ```

Notice that I've used `mode=simpleeditmode` on all three buttons. If you don't use `mode=simpleeditmode` you will end up with the EPiServer edit-mode interface in the header after saving and publishing your page.

`epslanguage` is not necessary if you only have your site in one language. I added it just in case sometime in the future we decide to make it multilingual.

`type` is hard-coded. Is there a way to implement this in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4):

This gives the URL for Edit Mode with the current page loaded. Compare it to the Quick Edit URL and tweak accordingly.

```
string.Format(
  "{0}default.aspx?id={1}&amp;epslanguage={2}&amp;selectededitpaneltab=1",
  UriSupport.AbsoluteUrlFromUIBySettings("edit/"),
  page.PageLink,
  page.LanguageBranch)
```

Comment: Note: In EPi 7 you have built-in properties for this.

Comment: Can you do the same but by creating a new page (of any type) using this method?

Comment: Are there any articles/blogposts out on the web regarding this subject?

Comment: New page should be even easier. Just look at the URL inside EPi when you try their link.

Comment: What about permissions for different logged in users - are there any potential problems you should take into consideration?

Comment: You should only show the link if the user has edit rights for the page. Check out page.QueryDistinctAccess()‎.